# How can i go to new component when a button is clicked but after some validations is done

Tags: reactjs, events, routes, onclick

I have a button that will send send otp and shows up a new screen where the user has to put the otp . But before that this buttton also calls a onClick function to validate the phone numbers.

I am trying to make the validations first and then call my second component with the same button . How can i do it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.